# Is it ok to change userInteractionEnabled property in another thread?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

This might be a noob question, but I want to change the userInteractionEnabled property of a view in a thread that is not the main thread, is this safe to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any interaction with UIKit should be done in the main thread.  That includes interaction with a UIView.

CORRECTION:

Some interactions with UIKIt are permissible in the main thread.  UIImage, UIColor, UIFont and Core Graphics are all threadsafe.